Running Cypress E2E Tests with Docker Compose in GitHub Actions - Facing Communication Issues
I'm trying to run my end-to-end (e2e) tests written with Cypress in a GitHub Actions workflow. My backend and databases are managed using Docker Compose. In my e2e test my Angular frontend is trying to make a call to my api gateway that is located in the docker-compose file. The call is using localhost:8080/ to communicate with the API gateway.
Here's the relevant part of my workflow YAML:
workflow:
on: workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  e2e-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Checkout Frontend Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          repository: repo/frontend
          path: frontend
      - name: Start Docker Compose
        run: docker-compose up -d --build
      - name: Show log from api-gateway
        run: docker logs "api-gateway"
      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v6
        with:
          build: npm run config | npm run build
          start: npm start
          wait-on: 'http://[::1]:4200'
          working-directory: frontend
          spec: cypress/e2e/post_tweet.cy.ts
          record: true
        env:
          CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY }}
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Stop Docker Compose
        run: docker-compose down

The Problem:
The Cypress tests are failing within the workflow. Locally, everything works perfectly when I run docker-compose up followed by cypress e2e.
What I've Tried:

Analyzed Docker Compose logs, but the output that I got (see image) is not helping.

Tried using individual services instead of docker-compose up, but the
issue persists.

My Concerns:

Are the containers guaranteed to be ready after running
docker-compose up -d?

Can the Cypress run step (from workflow) communicate with the containers using
localhost:port within the workflow?

Having the frontend also dockerized and add it to the docker compose yaml file.

How can I effectively debug this communication issue?


